# C1 CMS: Make blog URLs different from headings

Tags: url, content-management-system, blogs, composite, c1-cms

I am interested if we can separate URLs from blog headings (make them not dependent on H1)? Currently the URLs look the same as the Heading (Example: https://10.8.139.49/en-gb/ecopayz/blog/2016/11/03/Use-2-Step-Verification-for-Your-ecoAccount).

So, if we have uppercase in the H1 we'll have it in the URL as well. From usability point of you, it's not correct and we want to make URLs from lower case while Headings will be from capital and non-capital letters depending on the sense.

Maybe you know some ready plugins for this? Or have another ready solution?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I found the way out:

1) We should download https://github.com/Orckestra/CMS-Packages/tree/4c4a15411327fc1950fc6800f47730b48f171eb1/Composite.Community.Blog

2) From the ZIP, copy these files to your website (same folder location on website - overwrite existing files):

- /bin/Composite.Community.Blog.dll

  - /App_Data/Razor/Composite/Community/Blog/Latest.cshtml
- /App_Data/Razor/Composite/Community/Blog/BlogRenderer.cshtml

After this update - when you add/edit (and save) a blog post, the URL for the post will follow the rules you have defined for pages. These rules will by default not lower case things, but on http://docs.c1.orckestra.com/Configuration/UrlFormatting you can read how to make lower case URL mandatory.

Please be aware that these rules only apply to items ad "edit and save time" - you will not see URLs change immediately.